Frequent problems with program crashes and Aw, Snap!
Fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo T14s Gen1 with LVM and encryption.
Install went without issues, used the default disk layout. Added to livepatch.
Started experiencing the "Aw, Snap!" problems in Chromium, but also other snap based programs. Also experienced random crashes with other programs, including the error reporting tool in Ubuntu...
Example error messages:
chromium_chromium.desktop[61106]: [0815/084109.575607:ERROR:ptracer.cc(605)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
chromium_chromium.desktop[61106]: [0815/084109.659265:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found

mattermost-desktop.desktop[3394]: [3394:0807/205742.463384:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(274)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 4375: Permission denied (13)


update-notifier-crash[4351]: ERROR: Cannot update /var/crash/_usr_sbin_cups-browsed.115.crash: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/crash/_usr_sbin_cups-browsed.115.crash'

etc...

All packages was updated to their latest versions, nothing fancy installed, and everything from stable DEB (and snap) repos.
See my own answer below. I'm typing this up in the hope that 1) it will help somebody else, 2) somebody might be able to provide an answer that is not just a workaround.

Relevant forum post regarding limitations in snap: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/limitations-in-snapd/9718

Rethorical question since I'm the one asking the question:
Did you by any chance copy the HOME folder from your older laptop, with the $HOME/snap folder onto your new laptop?
This might lead to unexpected results.
Try moving / renaming the snap-folder and see if your issues are solved.
NB! You might want to try and open your programs and export / save settings, saved passwords, etc if this is important to you, before renaming the snap folder.
# OPTIONALLY stop all programs running as snaps
# As your regular user
pkill -u $(whoami) -f " /snap"

# Rename the snap folder
mv -f $HOME/snap $HOME/snap-$(date +%Y%m%d)

Now re-open the programs, or even reboot to start with a clean slate.

You have posted a picture, instead of {}-formatted text. It's unscrollable.  We cannot see the full error messages.

@waltinator It is properly formatted text in the question.

...I did, and removing the $HOME/snap folder and letting it recreate and re-populate solved all the issues...

https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots is relevant for backup/restore and/or migration to a new laptop, but I really only want to ensure that the config is possible to re-apply on a new laptop / if I need to re-install a snap, so I'll keep looking.
